# Visual studio is skipping the second scanf statement

Tags: c

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    float value1, value2;
    double returnValue; /* declaring the output of lollygag*/   /*declares the values that will be filled with user input*/
    printf("Enter a decimal value:  ");
    scanf(" %f ", &value1);

    printf("Enter the second decimal value:  ");
    scanf(" %f ", &value2);
    lollygag(value1, value2); /*calling the lollygag fuction in order to preform the operation*/
    printf(" %f ", returnValue); /*displays our final answer*/

}

float lollygag(returnValue, value1, value2) {


    if (value1==0 || value2==0)  /*tests to see if one of the values is 0*/
    {
        return -1.0;
        
    }
    else /* if neither value is 0 it will prefrom this operation*/
    {
        returnValue = value1 / value2; /*redefines retrunValue with our solution*/
    }
    return returnValue;
}
```

I use visual studio and when I run the program it basically skips the second `scanf` if I see a float value. It works just fine if I type an int. What would be causing this?

Comment: Do not tag unrelated languages.

Comment: When presenting questions, you should present code that _compiles_. Yours does not.

Comment: `scanf(" %f "` Remove the trailing whitespace in the format string. That is almost never what you want. See: [What is the effect of trailing white space in a scanf() format string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19499060/what-is-the-effect-of-trailing-white-space-in-a-scanf-format-string). The first whitespace is also unnecessary (but has less negative effects).

Comment: ok, I fixed that, but same issue, any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are adding spaces around your input format specifiers. Don’t do that.

Additionally, you are:

- Mixing floating point types. Pick one and stick to it.
- Not prototyping functions before you use them. (I always recommend declaring the entire function *before* you use it.)
- You need to read up more on using functions.

This should help:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>

float lollygag(float value1, float value2);  // function prototype

int main(void) {
    float value1;
    printf("Enter a decimal value:  ");
    scanf("%f", &value1);  // no spaces

    float value2;
    printf("Enter the second decimal value:  ");
    scanf("%f", &value2);
    
    float returnValue = lollygag(value1, value2); /*calling the lollygag fuction in order to preform the operation*/
    printf("%f\n", returnValue); /*displays our final answer*/

}

float lollygag(float value1, float value2) {
    float returnValue;

    if (value1==0 || value2==0)  /*tests to see if one of the values is 0*/
    {
        return -1.0;
        
    }
    else /* if neither value is 0 it will prefrom this operation*/
    {
        returnValue = value1 / value2; /*redefines retrunValue with our solution*/
    }
    return returnValue;
}
```

Oh, yeah, almost forgot. When compiling, always turn up the warning level to the highest you can within reason. I always compile with MSVC using warning level 4 (`/W4`). You could do just fine with warning level 3. <s>Somewhere in the VSCode options/settings/whatever (I have never used it) there is a spot where you can set that for the compiler.</s>
I just re-read the question, and see you are using VS. In VS right click on your project options and update the compile flags.

Sorry, one more edit: There are _two_ `returnValue` objects (variables) in the above program.

- One is declared in `main()`. It is assigned the result of calling `lollygag()`.
- The other is local to `lollygag()`.

They share the same name, but are not the same thing. You could easily change all the `returnValue`s in `lollygag()` to `quux` and the program would work the same.

The same thing holds true for argument names. The argument `value1` is a *different* object than the `value1` variable in `main()`.

Again, read up more on functions and this will eventually make sense.